# Nivo Slider - only a static image showing

Tags: jquery, css, slider, nivo-slider

I can't quite work out why the one image is just staying static.
There is no jQuery errors, so I am a bit stuck.

The styling is correct btw, the client have asked for it to be link that in case you think it is broken.

Thanks in advance!!

**Revision** It would be helpful to actually post a link to the site! Sorry about that http://bryngriffithsphotography.com/

Comment: We can't quite work out what is the question `:)` and where is the **Code** ? Welcome to SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask might help `:)`

Comment: Sorry about that, I completely forgot to add a link! Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

I'd stupidly wrapped all of the images in a single a tag, meaning it was repeating the same link rather than the images!
Doh!